# How to make a modal draggable in angular2 ?

Tags: modal-dialog, draggable

I Imported this modal from npm

import { ModalModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

Comment: Your question is unclear!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to drag your modal,
here is the link:

```
[https://codepen.io/adamcjoiner/pen/PNbbbv][1]
```